# graphviz, how stick nodes position on the image

Tags: tree, visualization, graphviz, dot

I have question about how visualise trees . Now I use [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) or [dot language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language) and have some problems.

Briefly about my context.
I have series of trees. Tree on step T is obtained from tree on step T-1 by adding some edges. I want to create image for each tree. 
Wile viewing these images in Image viewer I am clicking next button and want easily see changes in tree from step T-1 to step T.

What I am doing now. I wrote script that creates 'dot' code for creating image for each graph. While clicking on button ''next'' in Image viewer I see how nodes jump. But I don't like it. I want that nodes will stay on the same place on each picture, the only change I want see is how new edges and **new** nodes appear.

Is there way to stick nodes in their position?

Comment: Could you provide some examples of your `.dot` files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible. There is a `pos` attribute (containing the coordinates) of nodes and edges you'll have to use.

To get some examples of the values of `pos` you can simply invoke `dot` without any specified output format. This'll give you a `.dot` file with added coordinates.
So the file `minimal.dot`

```
digraph G {
  a [label="Node A"];
  b [label="Node B"];
  a -> b;
}
```

processed by `dot minimal.dot` will result in:

```
digraph G {
  node [label="\N"];
  graph [bb="0,0,82,108"];
  a [label="Node A", pos="41,90", width="1.14", height="0.50"];
  b [label="Node B", pos="41,18", width="1.14", height="0.50"];
  a -> b [pos="e,41,36 41,72 41,64 41,55 41,46"];
}
```

The edge and each node have now a `pos` attribute. This should get you started.